# RabbitMQ server performance issue - consuming messages

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

All,

I have a problem with the performance with RabbitMQ when consuming messages when there is a large amount of messages to be consumed e.g. 280,000. It seems to go up and down from a performance perspective. The graph illustrated in the diagram taken from the management console demonstrates this where a consumer averages around 40 messages per second but then jumps up to around 120 messages per second:

[image]

The pattern will repeat itself again where it will go back to 40 and up to 120 again etc
Also, if I run the same test 1 hour later, the same up and down effect occurs but the range can vastly vary e.g. from 140 to 400 messages per second.

Note: The consumer does nothing with the messages
Note: Single consumer and ConsumerMessagePrefetchCount = 500

In relation to performance I have the following questions:

1. Is this up and down behaviour normal and expected or should the consumption speed of messages be steady?
2. Are the numbers that I am quoting expected or should they be much better/worse?

Any help appreciated
Billy

Comment: How many RAM have in your server?
Have you tried to change vm_memory_high_watermark ?

Comment: Its running on a VM with 4 GB or RAM. The VMs sole responsibility is the rabbitmq server. The high watermark is 1.5 GB which is 40%. Memory currenly hitting max of 500MB so we are nowhere near high water mark.

Comment: Specify platform and rabbitmq version and client language/library

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, RabbitMQ 3.2.4, Erlang R14B04

Comment: RabbitMQ client library 3.2.4.0 http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html

Answer (score 0):

This behavior  is quite normal, the queues are designed to be always close to zero messages. 280,000 is an high number, it means that the producer is faster than the consumer(s) so you have to increase the consumers number.

If you have a spike load,  280,000 could be not high number because you have a time to consume the messages.
There are lots techniques to increase the performances, for example:

1. Increase the consumer threads, (How many threads do you use to
   consume the messages?)
2. Send messages with  noAck
3. PrefetchCount is very important, an high value couldn’t be a right
   solution.

The consumers should be steady, but also the producers should be steady, in load spike situation you need more time or more resources.

A few questions:
What rate do you have ?

1. Do you consume the messages from the same queue?
2. Do you  need the ACK?
3. Why do you have 280.000 messages to the queue? Is it just a test or
   a real situation ?

I hope it can be useful

> As said Alexis Richardson (RabbitMQ) :
>
> [The easiest way to increase performance is to change what you are measuring ;-)](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2009-May/003633.html)